# What is the correct way to return and receive transformed data from an observable in an Angular service and component?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, service, async-await, observable

I have a basic service that is configured to work as an Observable.

I injected the service into a component which subscribes to the service's following method which triggers an http request for data:

```
listApi(params:any) Observable<any[]> {
...
return this.http.get(params.url, ampOptions)
                    .map(data => this.listExtract(response, params))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I need to loop through and transform the response in such a way that it is guaranteed to complete *before* returning it to my component.

To achieve this, I attempted using an `async` function with `await` and a `Promise.all`:

```
async listExtract(response:any, params:any) {
  let newArray:any = [];
  await Promise.all(response.map((item, index) => {
      if(item.id === params.id) {
       // make changes to specific item if it's id is a match
       item.label = 'selected';
      }
      newArray.push(item);
  });
  // I am assuming the above promise.all is guaranteed
  // to complete before returning the new array, correct?
  return newArray;
}
```

In my component, I subscribe to the `listApi` method in my service:

```
this.listService.listApi(params)
      .subscribe(
        response => this.listServiceResponse(response),
        error => this.serviceError = <any>error);
```

The response *appears* to come through correctly, but because i am using a promise to transform the data, it is wrapped in an object titled `ZoneAwarePromise`:

```
listServiceResponse(response) {
   // because i used an async function in the service,
   // Angular returns the response wrapped in an
   // object titled ZoneAwarePromise
   console.log('response:',response);
}
```

If my approach above using an *async* function is valid for transforming the data first, how do I correctly receive this response? Or should I be going about this in an entirely different way?

I could just extract the response out of the `ZoneAwarePromise` object, but that does not seem reliable, and just as an example, the following *works*, but this can not possibly be the correct way to go about it either:

```
listServiceResponse(response) {
       // attempt to use a .then to extract the data
       response.then((extractedArray) => {
         console.log('response:',extractedArray);
       }
}
```

Is there another approach that maybe uses a more complex mapping method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the observable directly. The subscribe method won't get triggered until the content is returned by your service, so you should be able to do all the processing you need before that gets called.  I think you can simplify your `listExtract` so that it just deals with the action of transforming the response into your array of things, without worrying about any async business.

```
listExtract(response:any, params:any): any[] {
  let results: any[] = response.results;
  return results.map(item => {
    if (item.id == params.id)
      item.label = 'selected';
    return item;
  });
}
```

Then your `listApi` method can remain mostly the same, but you should actually use that `data` argument you have, which will be the http response.

```
listApi(params:any) Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get(params.url, ampOptions)
                    .map(data => this.listExtract(data, params))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then your use of this listApi service call should be simple enough in your component:

```
this.listService.listApi(params)
      .subscribe(array_of_things = this.workWithMyList(array_of_things));
```

The observable here should eliminate any need to manually deal with the async nature of your data.  When your subscribe gets triggered, the data will already be there.

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct because it solves the question i presented, but unfortunately i did not include some extra calculations that i need to take place following the map function before returning the response. So if you do not mind, can i ask, is the map function synchronous? Say i need to push some additional data onto the array after the mapping function completes. Is it safe to assume that instead of returning the map function itself, can i call the map function first, and THEN return the array further down in the method?

Comment: Yes. `map` just transforms the data in some way, and it is synchronous. It receives the response observable and transforms it into another observable, potentially of another type. If instead, for example, you need to pull in more info from a separate http resource or some other async process to augment the info on your objects, you should look into `flatMap`. If everything can be synchronous (after the http request, of course) then you can likely do it all in `map`.